# ruby on rails allow user to write posts in multiple languages at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm looking for a way to allow users to input posts in multiple languages. Then show only the one for the language of the users unless there is not one then fall back to the default or a listed default.

So far all I have been able to come up with is having multiple posts created each with a language tag and then do a check if post exists in the language requested and if not return the default.

Is there any better solution for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definitively use the [Globalize](https://github.com/globalize/globalize) gem. It's allow you to translate fields in your models and save this translations to your database.

It works with I18n current locale :

```
I18n.locale = :en
post.title = "english_title"
I18n.locale = :fr
post.title = "french_title"
post.save
I18n.locale = :en
post.title #=> "english_title"
I18n.locale = :fr
post.title #=> "french_title"
```

For your example you can use this syntax to render multiple post input in many language at once :

```
<% Globalize.with_locale(:fr) do %>
  <%= render "post_partial" %>
<% end %>
<% Globalize.with_locale(:en) do %>
  <%= render "post_partial" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This looks like what I am looking for because it allows the user to actually input in multiple languages. I assume this can be done by a form. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to implement a similar project and had an idea on implementation.

Using  easy translate gem (https://github.com/seejohnrun/easy_translate) You can use this statement to translate the post body

```
EasyTranslate.translate(@post.body, :to => :russian)
```

To make it personalised you could store user preferred language in the user record and do this

```
EasyTranslate.translate(@post.body, :to => current_user.language)
```

Answer (score 1):

Translations in Rails typically utilise [the `i18n` library](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html). ("18" stands for the 18 skipped letters in "internationalization".)

This is a very large topic, which I cannot reasonably cover in a single StackOverflow post - so I strongly suggest you spend some time reading through the official documentation.

However, in brief, there is no need for you to "reinvent the wheel" here by implementing your own language lookup tool. You can simply store `i18n` translations [in the database](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#using-different-backends) and fetch them according to the logged-in user's locale.

Comment: I know about the whole I18n library and how to use it. I've used it in this project for everything so far. but what I am trying to do is allow the user to make a post with text in many languages, thanks anyways

Comment: ...And I'm saying that you *can* use `i18n` for precisely this! Depending on your UI design, you may need some additional backend logic to store each translation in the correct place - but the problem can still be solved easily with `i18n`.

Comment: yeah I understand i18n can do this but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: If you want more specific advice on how to implement this in your application (what are you struggling with, exactly?), then I'd need more specific information on how your application works.

Comment: basically I was trying to find a way to allow the user to store multiple text entries one per language the user wishes to use. then retrieve and display these all from the database

Answer (score 1):

check out the multilang-hstore gem if you use Postgres

https://github.com/bithavoc/multilang-hstore

Answer (score 1):

If you are using postgreSQL you could use the hstore_translate gem. The hstore module implements hstore data type for storing key-value pairs in a single value in the database.

gemfile : `gem 'hstore_translate'`

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  translates :title, :body
end
```

in your migration :

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.column :title_translations, 'hstore'
      t.column :body_translations,  'hstore'
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
  def down
    drop_table :posts
  end
end
```

in your console :

```
I18n.locale = :en
post.title
```

enable fallbacks in your application.rb :
`config.i18n.fallbacks = true`